# Ruby Array Condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

How to store movies into new array if the rating is greater than 3?

```
movies = [
      {
        "id" => 70111470,
        "title" => "Die Hard",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 5.0,
        "bookmark" => []
      },
      {
        "id" => 654356453,
        "title" => "Bad Boys",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 2.0,
        "bookmark" => [{ "id" => 432534, "time" => 65876586 }]
      }
    ]
```

The result should give me the title and boxart only.

```
[
  {
    "title"=>"Die Hard",
    "boxart"=>"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby arrays have two methods that you can use to achieve what you want: `select` and `map`.

The select function takes in a block and returns elements for which the block returns true. https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select

The map function takes in a block and creates a new array where each element of the original array is *mapped* to a new element/object in the new array https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map

```
movies = [
      {
        "id" => 70111470,
        "title" => "Die Hard",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 5.0,
        "bookmark" => []
      },
      {
        "id" => 654356453,
        "title" => "Bad Boys",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 2.0,
        "bookmark" => [{ "id" => 432534, "time" => 65876586 }]
      }
    ]
    
p movies.select { |m|
    m["rating"] > 3.0
}.map { |m| 
    {
        "title" => m["title"],
        "boxart" => m["boxart"]
    }
}
```

In the code above, I first use the `select` function to only select movies with rating greater than 3. Once I get that array, I then use the `map` function to create a new array with only the fields that you mentioned above.

You can also write the same code by storing the intermediate results in a temporary variable

```
movies = [
      {
        "id" => 70111470,
        "title" => "Die Hard",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 5.0,
        "bookmark" => []
      },
      {
        "id" => 654356453,
        "title" => "Bad Boys",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 2.0,
        "bookmark" => [{ "id" => 432534, "time" => 65876586 }]
      }
    ]
    
movies_with_high_rating = movies.select { |m|
    m["rating"] > 3.0
}

result = movies_with_high_rating.map { |m| 
    {
        "title" => m["title"],
        "boxart" => m["boxart"]
    }
}

p result
```

Comment: @kevin accept the answer if he answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is two easy way to do this:

- First you can use collect for assign block scope value to variable:

  `result_array = movies.collect { |movie|  { title: movie['title'], boxart: movie['boxart'] }  if movie['rating'] > 3  }.compact`
- Second Way is use an array instantiated variable and push value inside block:

  `result_array = []`

  `movies.each {|movie| result_array << { title: movie['title'], boxart: movie['boxart'] } if movie['rating'] > 3 }`

Answer (score 0):

Use filter_map (Ruby 2.7+). Instead of a separate map and select, you can save the time associated
with the wasted map computations and a second iteration through the collection.

```
 movies.filter_map do |movie|
   if movie['rating'] > 3
    {title:  movie['title'],
     boxart: movie['boxart'] }
   end
end
```